# Difference between permutation and combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to learn permutation and combination but I can't differentiate between them, nor can I make out what they are? I have been trying to study them but I don't seem to understand them can anyone help me or suggest a good book for starting?

Comment: Just to introduce permutations and combinations or anything at school level, NCERT books do not good, but great job.

Comment: For combinatorics specific, Chen Chuan-Chong has good introductory book while Brualdi's Introductory Combinatorics is a standard text.

Comment: @cosmo5 True, NCERT is underrated when it comes to math explanation. I speak even at the level of 3rd/4th grade, I used to help some children at that level out with concepts. When you have PhDs writing textbooks for 1st class children rather than good educators, I think confusions like the ones our friend has above will be common.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, Indeed. We should be bit worried about the source of confusion, which is rooted in ignorance about the strength of authors as well as unwillingness of school students to write things down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In permutation `order`  matters while in combination `order` doesn't matter.

For example, suppose you have $3$ symbols $A,B,C$.

Then in case of permutation,  the permutation of $A,B,C$ are `ABC`, `BCA`, `CAB`  and all are different because here `order` matter while in case of combination all three are same, i.e.,  the combination of $A,B,C$ is just `ABC`,   here `order` doesn't matter.